# Build/Package Android application with rake?

Tags: android, rake, build-script

Is it possible to build an android application with rake? The only other question on this subject I saw was a while back and someone advised using Gradle.

So is there any way to do this on the command line, as I am sure under the hood eclipse just runs a lot of command line guff to get the apk file generated then spits it to the device, I just want to generate the apk file (there is alot of other things to be done but these are prior to the APK building).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to build an android application with rake?

Yes, insofar as it is possible to build an Android application using Ant, and rake can in theory do everything Ant can.

If you are expecting to find an existing rake script, though, you will likely be disappointed. The Ant scripts necessary to build an Android app are rather substantial, and porting all of that to rake will take quite some time. And, then, they will perpetually be out of date, as those Ant scripts are often modified with Android tools releases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example project that's worth a look: https://github.com/jberkel/android-helloworld-rake

I've been meaning to try it out myself.

Comment: Oh brilliant, I will go give it a whirl later